# Are the spaces BG for compact connected groups G ind-projective or ind-Kähler?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, equivariant-cohomology

Let $G$ be a compact connected group, or maybe better its complexification.  By thinking about the simplicial Borel space, or using $n$-acyclic $G$-spaces for higher and higher $n$, it's "easy" to see that $H^\bullet(BG)$ has a Hodge structure.  In fact, since $H^\bullet(BG)\to H^\bullet(BT)$ is injective, it's easy to see that this structure is pure and Tate.

For $G=U(n)/{\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})}$ or more generally a product of $U(n)$'s (so, for example, a torus, which I used above), there's a straightforward explanation of this point: $BG$ is an ind-projective variety, the Grassmannian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$.  For a construction I'm trying to use, my life will be much easier if I can figure out a similar presentation for other groups.

> Is this something special about $U(n)$, or can $BG$ for other compact groups also be thought of as a limit of projective (or just Kähler) varieties?  Is there a notion of complex structure on $BG$ where the Hodge-to-DeRham spectral sequence degenerates?

$\operatorname{SO(n)}$ in particular seems like it might be an issue, since it's a real Stiefel manifold.

Comment: It seems to me that if $BG$ is a direct limit of projective varieties then $H_2(BG)\cong \pi_2(BG)\cong \pi_1(G)$ must be infinite.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Good point.